# PHP CURL authorization. How to check if authorization ttl has expired?

Tags: php, authentication, curl

who knows solution - help me please.

I have script which do next on user get page:

```
1. read some data from DB.
2. build url 
3. CURL request 1 : do authorization using curl.
4. CURL request 2 : load and parse some content.
5. give user page content based on 4th list item.
```

How can I check if my authorization session\cookie expired or not? 
I want to run 3rd item of list only when its expired to waste less time on curl requests (site-donor is too slow and response in 10-15 sec on any page request)

Thanks!

Comment: How many "step #4s" will you be doing?  I have software that does this quite a lot, and have never needed to reauthorize ...

Comment: per each page request to my site I do 1 page request to another.
But also I do 3rd step before to be sure that I will parse content what is actual for my account at site-donor

Comment: You can check on the life of the cookie: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html Also, depending on the authorization, can check for failed login status code and re-auth when encountered.

Comment: the site donor is a b2b platform based structure and each time I send request I'll get in 15 seconds content anyway! But if this content is actual for my account(wholesaler) or for guest(retailer) it depends on my authentication data. 

So: I send one request to force authorization (15 sec) and another to get content(15sec), so loading of the content is 30 sec.
if try to do in your way:  request (15) to get content; if auth is ok : total 15 sec, but if not = request to auth (+15 sec) and request to get content (+15 sec) total is (45) - what is greater in a half

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found is to look on user authorization block markup.

And check which node exists:

```
<button type="submit" name="action" value="login">Login</button>
```

Or

```
<button type="submit" name="action" value="logout">Logout</button>
```

it's + 1 CURL query to check if server indicate us as authorized user. But it works..